# Vue.js: como relacionar valores em um array de strings?

Tags: array, vue.js, toggle

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um array de strings que monta uma lista:

ex:

```
op: ['100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '200', '201', '202', '300', '301', '303', '500']
```

A partir dessa lista, eu crio através do **v-for** vários "toggles" que podem ser habilitados/desabilitados, quando ele é ativado, eu passo para outro array, as strings ativas:

ex:

```
opSelecionado: ['100', '101', '102', '200']
```

A dificuldade é relacionar os números com final "00" com os outros, por exemplo, quando eu desativar o '100', os valores '101' e '102' devem ser removidos desse novo array ou quando ativar o '101' o '100' deve ficar habilitado.

Isso é possível com esses arrays de string?

Segue um exemplo criado no [codepen](https://codepen.io/haykou/pen/jRydOL?editors=1010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um **@click** no seu input onde chama um method para verificar suas regras e atualizar o array de opções selecionadas com a função **filter** de acordo com essas regras.

Segue link do codepen com esse exemplo funcionando: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWpXqB

Answer (score 2):

Podes capturar o click nos checkboxes e checar se o "grupo" deve ser desabilitado, de acordo com o elemento clicado. Segue um [codepen](https://codepen.io/espindolaa/pen/qwrXzQ?editors=1010).